# MySQL full inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have

```
SELECT clientReport.id 
FROM clientReport 
LEFT JOIN report02 ON (report02.id = clientReport.id)
WHERE report02.id is null;
```

that does the equivalent of

```
SELECT clientReport.id
WHERE clientReport.rowNumber NOT EXISTS (
SELECT clientReport.rowNumber FROM report02, clientReport
WHERE report02.id=clientReport.id);
```

I need, presumably, a full inner join to also get mismatches in report02, not just clientReport. How do I write the join to do this?

Comment: edited and added the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work.

```
SELECT clientReport.id,report02.id
FROM clientReport 
FULL OUTER JOIN report02 ON (report02.id = clientReport.id)
WHERE report02.id is null
OR clientReport.id is null;
```

It should but it doesn't (as MySQL does not currently support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.)

This is more likely to work:

```
( SELECT clientReport.id  AS report01
       , report02.id      AS report02
  FROM clientReport 
  LEFT  OUTER JOIN report02
      ON (report02.id = clientReport.id)
  WHERE report02.id IS NULL
)
UNION
( SELECT clientReport.id  AS report01
       , report02.id      AS report02
  FROM clientReport 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN report02
      ON (report02.id = clientReport.id)
  WHERE clientReport.id is null
)
```

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer joins. You need a union of a left and a right join for this to work with MySQL.